# Converting circular structure to JSON\n error in node js express, while verifying token

Tags: javascript, node.js

Iam creating user registration form. I have executed user authentication and login successfully. But while verifying token, I strucked with this error i.e,

Converting circular structure JSON\n

In response:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

X-Powered-By: Express

Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Content-Length: 222

ETag: W/"de-9ml+cgt7g6sXsbHjg8OBuxCWLJQ"

Date: Thu, 29 Feb 2024 13:21:50 GMT

Connection: close

{

"errMessage": "Converting circular structure to JSON\n    --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'\n    |     property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'\n    --- property 'socket' clo# # ses the circle"

}

**Request.http module**

POST http://localhost:4000/user-api/login

Content-Type: application/json

{

"username":"satish",

"password":"satish",

"email":"satish@123"

}

GET http://localhost:4000/user-api/protected

Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InNhdGlzaCIsImlhdCI6MTcwOTIxMjg5MywiZXhwIjoxNzA5MjEyOTkzfQ.bY52QhQ7yWa7X1e0HTENW2XK-X9xczesLgzMx_ZBrL0

**VerifyToken.js Module**

const jsonwebtoken=require('jsonwebtoken')const circularJSON=require('circular-json')const verifyToken=(req,res,next)=>{const bearerToken=req.headers.authorizationif(!bearerToken) return res.send({message:"Unauthorized Request"})//extract only token from bearertokenconst token=bearerToken.split(' ')[1]let json=circularJSON.stringify(req)try{//verify token by decodong using same secrete keylet decodedToken=circularJSON.stringify(jsonwebtoken.verify(token,'abcdef')) next()}catch(err){ next(err)}}module.exports=verifyToken;

**userApi.js**

//Loging in by verifing credentials

userapp.post('/login',async(req,res)=>{

const userCredObj=req.body;

//verify username

const dbUser= await user.findOne({username:userCredObj.username})

if(dbUser===null)

res.send({message:"Invalid Username"})

else{

```
//we need to compare plain password with hashed password by using compare method

const status=bcryptjs.compare(userCredObj.password,dbUser.password)

if(status===false)

 res.send({message:"Invalid password"})

else{

 //create JWT token and send to the client

const signedToken= jsonwebtoken.sign({username:dbUser.username},'abcdef',{expiresIn:100})

res.send({message:"login success",token:signedToken})
```

}

}

})

//protected Routes

userapp.get('/protected',verifyToken,(req,res)=>{

res.send({message:"Protected route",payload:req})

})

How to handle this error.....

Comment: Which `res.send` is throwing this error?  I assume it’s not “login success” but likely “protected route”.  Please verify.

Comment: Yeah thank you I got it, for the confirmation I was printing the req object to the console, I forgot to remove it now it's working if I remove it.